# move_uploaded_file returns true but does not execute if statement

Tags: php

I am using PHPMailer for sending mail with attachment. I am saving the file on the server first and for this, I'm using PHP `move_uploaded_file` function.

The problem is when I debug my code, `move_uploaded_file` function returns true but it does not execute any statement inside `if` the condition and jump inside the else condition.

I don't understand this behaviour if the condition is true then `if statement` should be executed. Please let me know the problem.

**Here is my code**

```
        $targetfolder = "docs/cv/";
        $new_file_name = md5($_FILES['cv']['tmp_name']);

        //$targetfolder = $targetfolder . basename($_FILES['cv']['tmp_name']);
        $targetfolder = $targetfolder . $new_file_name . '.png';
        $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['cv']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        //if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['cv']['tmp_name'], $targetfolder))
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['cv']['tmp_name'], $targetfolder))
        {
           echo "Uploaded";
        }
        else {
           echo "Not Uploaded";
        }
```

Comment: _“function returns true but it does not execute any statement inside if the condition and jump inside the else condition.”_ - that is so close to being technically impossible, that it doesn’t even warrant considering as the actual error. Might be a mistake in _how_ you tried to debug this in the first place. Take the function call out of the if, store its result in a variable, make a var_dump of that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    $targetfolder = "docs/cv/";
    $new_file_name = md5($_FILES['cv']['tmp_name']);

    //$targetfolder = $targetfolder . basename($_FILES['cv']['tmp_name']);
    $targetfolder = $targetfolder . $new_file_name . '.png';
    $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['cv']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    //if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['cv']['tmp_name'], $targetfolder))
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['cv']['tmp_name'], $targetfolder) === true)
    {
       echo "Uploaded";
    }
    else {
       echo "Not Uploaded";
    }
```

Comment: Hi @fahad shaikh Is this answer solved your problem?